# How to call a keyword stored in another project?

Tags: robotframework

I have two projects. In the first one, I have to call a keyword (with arguments). But, this keyword is stored in another project.

Another difficulty is that, I have to do this call through command line...

Do you have any idea to do that please? To call a keyword which is in another project?

Thank you. Regards

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is not possible.

You must have that keyword defined in a resource file (or library) and call it from a test case, or from other keyword.